# SQL Where clause 'that begins with'?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

In my rails application i have an SQL query tha tuses where and like to search for a query (params[:q]). How can i change it so query/:q cant be anywhere within the row, but must BEGIN with it? Here the code:

```
 AccountNumber.where("account_number like?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the leading `%` wildcard from the string.

```
AccountNumber.where("account_number like?", "#{params[:q]}%")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the '%' at the front

like this

```
AccountNumber.where("account_number like?", "#{params[:q]}%")
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard character '%' can be used anywhere in the query to indicated that a string of any length can be found there.  Remove the first '%' to search for results that only start with the #{params[:q]} rather than contains it:

```
AccountNumber.where("account_number like?", "#{params[:q]}%")
```